# How can I avoid this error "couldn't execute "des": no such file or directory"?

Tags: expect, tcl

I'm trying to do encryption in Expect as outlined [in this wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Secure+expect) on Ubuntu 16.04. I've installed ***tcllib***

```
root@alarmux:/home/abdmin# apt-get install tcllib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
tcllib is already the newest version (1.17-dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 77 not upgraded.
```

However, when I run my script I get:

```
couldn't execute "des": no such file or directory
    while executing
"exec echo "$pd" | des -e -k $key -b > /home/abdmin/$filename"
    (procedure "utility_encrypt" line 3)
    invoked from within
"utility_encrypt pswd encrypted_Pass"
    (file "./tclTest" line 22)
```

Why can't the `des` command be executed?

Comment: you need to install "des"   command

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the [tcllib des package](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/des/des.html)?

Comment: That document's content is 13 years old. Encryption has moved on a very long way in that time. Don't use DES; it's crackable in seconds (or less).

Comment: @roaima I know :) I just want to avoid having plaintext passwords in my script to avoid over-the-shoulder reading.

Comment: Encryption for the TCL script itself? Or are you using the TCL just to generate encrypted/decrypted passwords for a more complex shell script?

Comment: @roaima that's correct. The tcl is just encrypting a password which will be decrypted for use in an expect script which is run by a bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481781/how-can-i-avoid-this-error-couldnt-execute-des-no-such-file-or-directory?noredirect=1#comment882233_481781), if all you want to do is to avoid shoulder-surfing for cleartext passwords you can use a trivial encoding. For example, here's one in Perl

```
# Generate encoding
echo secret123 | perl -e 'chomp($passwd=<>); chomp($encoded=pack("u",$passwd));print "$encoded\n"'
)<V5C<F5T,3(S
```

Here the encoded password for `secret123` is `)<V5C<F5T,3(S`.

```
# Restore cleartext
echo ')<V5C<F5T,3(S' | perl -e 'chomp($encoded=<>); chomp($passwd=unpack("u",$encoded)); print "$passwd\n"'
secret123
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try. Should I apt install perl first?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you didn't have a basic install already. Failing that I can put an encoder together in shell script

Comment: OK, I'll give it a go! My plan is to encode my password just once and say the encoded file. The script can decode as necessary without anyone seeing the plaintext. Thank you for this.

Comment: I suppose base64 would work as well, or even just rot13.

Answer (score 1):

That page lists multiple solutions, so you'll need to use only one of them, or something else, depending on exactly what you're trying to do.

1. The `des` command code relies on some external binary called `des`. This command is not provided by TCL, nor by `tcllib`. It may be something ancient once used for (old, bad, insecure) DES or 3DES encryption. You will need to find the `des` command or use something compatible.
2. `tcllib` does provide a [`des(n)`](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/des/des.html) interface, but that does not appear to be documented on the page you linked. DES is, again, very weak and very old.
3. `tcllib` does provide a [`md5crypt(n)`](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/md5crypt/md5crypt.html) interface which is mentioned on the page you linked.

Something like PGP or `bcrypt` or `scrypt` may be better options over the DES or MD5 crypt algorithms, though it's not clear what problem you are trying to solve...do you need DES for compatibility with something ancient? How exactly are these secrets being used?

Comment: https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/des/des.html links to http://tcldes.sourceforge.net which states “**TclDES and TclDESjr are now part of tcllib!**”, it’s just the version packaged for Ubuntu that doesn’t ship `des`.

Comment: OpenSSL still includes several DES modes, and even provides a similar interface to the one this script expects (it knows `-e` and `-k key`, but not `-b`).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file list of the `tcllib` package for Ubuntu 16.04 [here on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/tcllib/filelist), it doesn’t contain a file like `/usr/bin/des` which you’re trying to run – and neither does any other package from the official repos. The only alternative I see is to [download the software](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/uv/tcllib-1.19.tar.gz) and (after purging the `tcllib` package) compile it yourself as explained here: [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that the support for des had essentially been dropped. I'll explore other options.

Comment: @KuboMD You’re welcome! If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.